# XamChart axis labels get cut off

Tags: xaml, charts, infragistics, axis-labels

I'm working with some XamCharts in Blend 4, WPF. Chart data gets loaded via .xml files, but this is not the problem.

My problem is that the axis labels get cut off. So instead of using less space for the bar chart it decides to cut off the labels. Is there a way of increasing the amount of space the labels use in relation to the graph visuals?

I've tried increasing the size of the XamChart itself, but this stretches the chart out needlessly, screwing up my layout!

All I want is for the label text to not get cut off, regardless of how much space the chart takes up. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

[Cut-off labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTTPu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The XamChart is using a Scene which is derived from ContentControl and within this is a ScenePane which derives from ChartCanvas and that derives from Canvas.  The Scenepane contains an AxisLabelsPane for the labels.

The challenge to sizing the labels is that the ScenePane, ChartCanvas, and AxisLabelsPane are all internal and the size reserved for the labels is hard coded.

The two options that you have are to get the source code for the XamChart and change it in the source code or to use reflection to change the values.  Since the XamChart has been retired by Infragistics and will not have any more bug fixes I would recommend getting the source code and making the changes you need there.

If you do wish to use reflection the following logic when added to the ChartRendered event will double the size of the x-axis labels on the bottom of the chart though doesn't prevent the chart from rendering over the top of the labels once moved:

```
Scene scene = this.AssociatedObject.Scene;
Type sceneType = typeof (Scene);
PropertyInfo scenePaneProperty = sceneType.GetProperty("ScenePane",
                                                        BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Canvas scenePane = scenePaneProperty.GetValue(scene, null) as Canvas;
Type scenePaneType = scenePane.GetType();
Type chartCanvasType = scenePaneType.BaseType;
FieldInfo horizontalAxisLabelsPanel1FieldInfo = scenePaneType.GetField("_labelsHorizontal1",
                                                                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                BindingFlags.GetField);
Canvas horizontalAxisLabelsPanel1 = horizontalAxisLabelsPanel1FieldInfo.GetValue(scenePane) as Canvas;

PropertyInfo relativePositionProperty = chartCanvasType.GetProperty("RelativePosition",
                                                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                                    BindingFlags.GetProperty);
relativePositionProperty.SetValue(horizontalAxisLabelsPanel1, new Rect(0,70,100,30),null);
```